# .csv delimiter in between every letter in output

Tags: python, csv

I'm scraping a website for some information and I've been writing it to a .csv; however whenever I run this script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time

site = "url"

with open('receipts_10.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    outfile = 'test.csv'
    ofile = open(outfile,"wb")
    writer = csv.writer(ofile,delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:

        response = requests.post(site, params={'appReceiptNum':row})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
        caseStatus = soup.find("h4")
        for string in caseStatus.stripped_strings:
            writer.writerow(string)
```

I end up with the following output in my csv:

```
I;n;i;t;i;a;l; ;R;e;v;i;e;w
D;e;c;i;s;i;o;n
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `site = "url'` should be `site = "url"`? Please fix your indentation as well.

Comment: Maybe this `writer.writerow(string)` should be this `writer.writerow(newString)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The csv.writerow(iterable) expects an iterable that its elements will be separated with the system (or default) separator.

The string object in python is an iterable too, the characters of the string are the elements of the iterable, so when you use this method with an alone string its characters are separated.

To avoid this behaviour you can use a list or a tuple that contains your string.

```
    for string in caseStatus.stripped_strings:
            newString = string.replace(" ", "")
            writer.writerow([newString])
```

Comment: I edited the code to avoid the use of an unnecessary empty list. It's quite easy to create them as they are needed, and makes the code rather more comprehensible.

Comment: @holdenweb I accept your suggestion, it's more clear the code with your solution.